# How can use documents4j on linux?

Tags: java, spring, documents4j

I am working on spring mvc web project on windows and my server is installed on linux. I am using documents4j for docx file convert to pdf file and it works fine on windows but when i put the code to the server it doesn't work because my server is on linux. Can documents4j work on linux? Or which library can I use instead of documents4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

documents4j works only if you have MS Word installed in your system, which is not possible on linux. I suggest you to do this :
Install libre office on linux and run this :

```
  String command = "libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf " + inputWordFilePath + " --outdir " + outputPdfPath;
 
 try {
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

documents4j can work on Linux but not all of its converters. If you are using MS Word or MS Excel, naturally, you will have to use Windows.

Comment: That's a pain..documents4j  was the only library out of these: opensagres, apachePOI and docx4j that converted the docx file  into a pdf with the same formatting and without any errors. When I tried to run this in Bamboo it failed, and I've discovered that it relies on MS converters..Bummer!  So how the hell I make this working in unix based envs ? is there any chance to make it work ? Btw, thanks for the contribution to opensource world and to this library !

Comment: If you can get Word and VBS run on Linux, it could work, but I doubt it's possible. Typically, you run the conversion on a remote Windows server.